# Django Rest framework, how to include '__all__' fields and a related field using foreignkey_id field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So here is my files -
Models.py

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    other_fields = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

Serializers.py

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = '__all__'


Here  json request
{"user_id":1, "other_fields":"details"}
```

and in views.py

```
serializer = MySerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.data

**Throws keyerror "user"**
```

When i try to change request parameter 
    "user_id" to "user" it works for me .
But I can't change request json. Is there any way to handle this issue in serializer?

*I can set all the fields inplace of '**_all_**' but it is not a good solution due to large number of fields .*

I also tried with -

```
 class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.CharField(source='user_id')
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = '__all__'
```

but it was not worked for me.

Comment: Why not try to use ```exclude``` param in your ```Meta``` class, pass it a tuple of not required fields.

Comment: quick question, is your database normalized?

Comment: Are you trying to get all the field on the `User` model as well ?

Comment: Usually, **`__all__`** will include **all model fields** + **fields included explicitly in serializer**

Comment: @e4c5, Yes my database is noramized

Comment: @Tobey, No I only wants user_id

Comment: @juliansalas, I already tried with Exclude but it raise
AssertionError: Cannot set both 'fields' and 'exclude' options on serializer MySerializer.

Comment: @JPG, You are right, but in my case i need to exclude = user , and include=user_id

Comment: ok, you have to use either fields or exclude but  you can't use both. Just use the ```exclude = ( 'user',)``` that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), source='user', write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        data = data.copy() # incase request data is immutable
        data['user'] = data['user_id']
        return super().to_internal_value(data)

    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = '__all__'
```

This should allow for payload:

```
 {"user_id": 1, "other_fields": "details"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using [**`viewset`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewsets) class for your views. then this will work
Override the **`__init__`** method as,

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'view' in self.context and self.context['view'].action in ['create', 'update', 'partial_update']:
            self.fields['user_id'] = self.fields.pop('user')

    class Meta:
        model = Model1
        fields = '__all__'
```

The ***`['create', 'update', 'partial_update']`*** are the [**`actions`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions) of **`viewset`** class which are representing **HTTP POST**, **HTTP PUT** and **HTTP PATCH** respectively.